# How to see the reason for "could not connect to the web server" running Rails project in Netbeans 6.7/6.8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans

I have a legacy Rails project (2.4) that used to work in Netbeans. But I just tried running it and got the message

```
"could not connect to the web server http://localhost:3000"
```

How do I get a more detailed explanation from Netbeans?

I don't see any other error information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Netbeans will be writing it's STDERR messages, either to a console window or a logfile.